# Can it be proven in ZFC that 2^aleph 1 is strictly larger than 2^aleph 0.

Tags: set-theory

Can it be proven in ZFC that $2^{\aleph_1} > 2^{\aleph_0}$? I have heard that the statement $c < d \rightarrow 2^c < 2^d$ cannot be proven in ZFC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is consistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}$ that $2^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_1}=\aleph_2$ (where $\aleph_2$ can be replaced by almost any cardinal). This can be shown to be consistent with a two step iteration of Cohen forcings over a model of $\mathsf{GCH}$.

The general result here is Easton's theorem. In $\mathsf{ZFC}$ there are two results that can be proved about cardinal arithmetic for regular cardinals, namely that $\kappa<\lambda$ implies $2^\kappa\leq 2^\lambda$ and that $\mathrm{cof}(2^\kappa)>\kappa$. Easton's theorem says that for regular cardinals you can't prove anything else, formally if $F$ is a class function from regular cardinals to cardinals satisfying $\kappa<\lambda\implies F(\kappa)\leq F(\lambda)$ and $\mathrm{cof}(F(\kappa))>\kappa$, then it is consistent that $2^\kappa=F(\kappa)$ for every regular $\kappa$